# Xamarin, How to invoke Shared code Method from Platform specific Dependency class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin forms app, How can we invoke Shared code Method from Platform specific Dependency class.

I need to call one method implemented in my ContentPage class from my iOS dependency class.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to this:

- Use a static method to call it where ever you need to.
- Use the messaging center to send a message to your Shared/PCL project and do what ever you need. (link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)
- If this is a Custom renderer you can use binded command properties and Execute those in your platforms specific code.

In my case, what I did was having a static class called Helper, that contains all the static methods that I need to call on all platforms/projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.